# What is the query to get the process limit on Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, limits

I'm getting the error:

```
Maximum Number Of Process Exceeded
```

I want to see (using a query) what the setting is in my database for the process limit.

My question is: **What is the query to get the process limit on Oracle 11g?**

Comment: `show parameter processes`

Comment: Thanks - could you expand that into an answer - showing me what I'm looking for in the result?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams202.htm#REFRN10175

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a more nuanced view of the limits and usage

```
select 
  resource_name, 
  current_utilization, 
  max_utilization, 
  limit_value 
from v$resource_limit 
where resource_name in ('sessions', 'processes');
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26061422/851930)

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(maxval) as PROCESS_LIMIT 
from dba_hist_sysmetric_summary 
where METRIC_NAME in ('Process Limit %');
```